# In laravel I have one error in my code. I want to connect datatable to laravel when user login

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, datatable, logout

Every one. Nice to meet you.
My code is below.

-controller.php

```
public function admin(Request $request) {
   if ($request->ajax()) {
     $users = \DB::table('users')->leftJoin('roles', 'users.role_id', '=', 'roles.id')->select('users.id as id', 'roles.name as role_name', 'users.*')->get();
...
   return Datatables::of(results)->make();
}
   return view('frontend.homepage.admin');
```

-web.php

```
Route::prefix("admin")->middleware(["auth:admin"])->group(function(){
    Route::get('dashboard', ['as' => 'homepage.admin', 'uses' => 'PagesController@admin']);    
});
```

But I have one error like as below.

{
    "message": "",
    "exception": "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException",
    "file": "E:\Uniclix_Source\API\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection.php",
    "line": 179,
    "trace": [
        {
            "file": "E:\Uniclix_Source\API\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php",
            "line": 636,
            "function": "match",
            "class": "Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "E:\Uniclix_Source\API\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php",
            "line": 625,
            "function": "findRoute",
            "class": "Illuminate\Routing\Router",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "E:\Uniclix_Source\API\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php",
            "line": 614,
            "function": "dispatchToRoute",
            "class": "Illuminate\Routing\Router",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "E:\Uniclix_Source\API\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php",
            "line": 176,
            "function": "dispatch",
            "class": "Illuminate\Routing\Router",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "E:\Uniclix_Source\API\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 30,
            "function": "Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel",
            "type": "->"
        }

Who can help me?

Comment: What is the route you're trying to use to access the page?

Comment: Yes, why I have the error?

Comment: That wasn't a yes-or-no question. I was asking, what is the route that you're using to access the page? From the looks of it, your URL should have `/admin/dashboard`. You can verify all of your routes by doing `php artisan routes:list` to see all of your registered routes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because of the url setting issue.
Perhaps the error code would be "404".
Please check the api endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

NotFoundHttpException raises when specified route does not exist.

According to your code, your route is **/admin/dashboard**.